# Convert unordered lists (<ul>) into HTML-formatted tables (<table>)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table, html-lists

I have previously been asking for a solution that would allow me to convert an unordered list into a formatted HTML table.

At that time, a kind user suggested a solution that I have attached below.

That solution turns the unordered list into a regular table in Google Sheets where the different values are divided into their own cells. Instead, I would like the unordered list to be turned into a formatted html table list placed in only one cell.

If possible, on top of this I would like to be able to throw in hundreds of unordered lists into the script that would then be converted into each of their own HTML-formatted table.

See the previous solution that I got from another user here below.

Hope it all makes sense.

**EDIT:**
I have also added input and preferred output at the very bottom of this post.

```
In your situation, how about the following sample script?

Sample script 1:
This script parses your value using the regex.

function myFunction1() {
  // This sample value is from your question.
  const sample = `<ul>
 <li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
 <li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
 <li>Fit: Regular unisex</li>
 <li>Elasticated waistband with drawstring</li>
 <li>Elasticated cuffs with tonal coated zips</li>
 <li>Single back pocket with eyelet</li>
 <li>Concealed side pockets</li>
 <li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
 <li>Reflective accents</li>
 </ul>`;
 
  // Parse list.
  const obj = sample.matchAll(/<li>([\w\S\s]+?)<\/li>/g);
  const values = [...obj].map(e => {
    if (e && e.length > 1) {
      const temp = e[1].split(":");
      return temp.length == 1 ? [temp[0].trim(), ""] : temp.map(f => f.trim());
    }
    return ["", ""];
  });

  // Put the values to the sheet.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
When this script is run, your sample value is parsed. And, the values are put to the sheet.
Sample script 2:
This script parses your value using XmlService.

function myFunction1() {
  // This sample value is from your question.
  const sample = `<ul>
 <li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
 <li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
 <li>Fit: Regular unisex</li>
 <li>Elasticated waistband with drawstring</li>
 <li>Elasticated cuffs with tonal coated zips</li>
 <li>Single back pocket with eyelet</li>
 <li>Concealed side pockets</li>
 <li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
 <li>Reflective accents</li>
 </ul>`;

  // Parse list.
  const root = XmlService.parse(sample).getRootElement();
  const values = root.getChildren("li", root.getNamespace()).map(e => {
    const temp = e.getValue().split(":");
    return temp.length == 1 ? [temp[0].trim(), ""] : temp.map(f => f.trim());
  });

  // Put the values to the sheet.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
References:
map()
setValues(values)
Added:
From your following additional question,

That does the job for doing it on one single product. Let's say I have a batch of product details for several different products. Like here below. Is there a way to run the script on all three at once so it becomes three different tables?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

Sample script:
function myFunction2() {
  // This is from your new question.
  const samples = [
    "<ul><li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li><li>Lining: 100% polyester</li><li>Insulation: 100% polyester</li><li>Measurements: H160cm x W140cm x D1cm / H63 x W55.1 x 0.4 inches</li><li>When packed: H13cm x W47cm x D25cm / H5.1 x W18.5 x D9.8 inc </li><li>Pack-carry-store system with buckles and adjustable webbing straps</li><li>Soft, quilted and padded side</li><li>Waterproof upper on reverse</li></ul>",
    "<ul><li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li><li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li><li>Soft mesh lining</li><li>Circumference: S1 – 61.5 cm / 24.2 inches, / S2 - 66 cm / 26 inches</li></ul>",
    "<ul><li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li><li>Lining: 100% polyester </li><li>Water column pressure: 8000mm</li><li>Measurements: H16 x W21 x D8.5cm / H6.3 x W8.3 x D3.3 inches</li><li>Volume: 3 liters / 0.8 gallons</li><li>Coated tonal zip closure</li><li>Single main compartment </li><li>Detachable adjustable webbing shoulder strap </li><li>Carry handle</li></ul>"
  ];
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"]; // Please set the sheet names.
  samples.forEach((sample, i) => {
    const root = XmlService.parse(sample).getRootElement();
    const values = root.getChildren("li", root.getNamespace()).map(e => {
      const temp = e.getValue().split(":");
      return temp.length == 1 ? [temp[0].trim(), ""] : temp.map(f => f.trim());
    });
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  });
}
```

See the input and preferred output here below.

Whenever there is a line of text with a colon, like "Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating", I would like it to be split into two columns in the table, so that "Material:" is in column 1, and "100% polyester with polyurethane coating" is in column 2.

**Input:**

```
/** List 1 **/
<ul>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Lining: 100% polyester</li>
<li>Insulation: 100% polyester</li>
<li>Measurements: H160cm x W140cm x D1cm / H63 x W55.1 x 0.4 inches</li>
<li>When packed: H13cm x W47cm x D25cm / H5.1 x W18.5 x D9.8 inc </li>
<li>Pack-carry-store system with buckles and adjustable webbing straps</li>
<li>Soft, quilted and padded side</li>
<li>Waterproof upper on reverse</li>
</ul>

/** List 2 **/

<ul>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
<li>Circumference: S1 – 61.5 cm / 24.2 inches, / S2 - 66 cm / 26 inches</li>
<li>Soft mesh lining</li>
</ul>

/** List 3 **/

<ul>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Lining: 100% polyester </li>
<li>Water column pressure: 8000mm</li>
<li>Measurements: H16 x W21 x D8.5cm / H6.3 x W8.3 x D3.3 inches</li>
<li>Volume: 3 liters / 0.8 gallons</li>
<li>Coated tonal zip closure</li>
<li>Single main compartment </li>
<li>Detachable adjustable webbing shoulder strap </li>
<li>Carry handle</li>
</ul>
```

**Wanted output:**

```
/** Table 1 (converted from List 1) **/
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Material:</td>
    <td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lining:</td>
    <td>100% polyester</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Insulation:</td>
    <td>100% polyester</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Measurements:</td>
    <td>H160cm x W140cm x D1cm / H63 x W55.1 x 0.4 inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>When packed:</td>
    <td>H13cm x W47cm x D25cm / H5.1 x W18.5 x D9.8 inc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pack-carry-store system with buckles and adjustable webbing straps</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Soft, quilted and padded side</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waterproof upper on reverse</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

/** Table 2 (converted from List 2) **/

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Material:</td>
    <td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Water column pressure:</td>
    <td>4000mm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Circumference:</td>
    <td>S1 – 61.5 cm / 24.2 inches, / S2 - 66 cm / 26 inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Soft mesh lining</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

/** Table 3 (converted from List 3) **/

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Material:</td>
    <td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lining:</td>
    <td>100% polyester</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Water column pressure:</td>
    <td>8000mm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Measurements:</td>
    <td>H16 x W21 x D8.5cm / H6.3 x W8.3 x D3.3 inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Volume:</td>
    <td>3 liters / 0.8 gallons</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Coated tonal zip closure</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Single main compartment</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Detachable adjustable webbing shoulder strap</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Carry handle</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show how your input and output should look like. You can create a couple of the lists and table manually and add the screenshots to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have now added the input and preferred output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I'd propose to try to use a custom formula like this:

```
function to_table(range) {

  const do_replace = text => text
    .replace(/<ul>/g,   '<table>')
    .replace(/<\/ul>/g, '</table>')
    .replace(/<li>/g,   '  <tr>\n    <td>')
    .replace(/<\/li>/g, '</td>\n  </tr>')
    .replace(/: /g, ':</td>\n    <td>')
    .replace(/(<tr>\n    <td>.+?<\/td>\n)(  <\/tr>)/gm, '$1    <td></td>\n$2');

  try { return range.map(row => do_replace(row[0])) } // for a range
  catch(e) { return do_replace(range) }               // for a single cell
}
```

To process a single cell:

[image]

To process a whole column:

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuri. Thanks a lot for the help! I have tried putting in the formula as suggested by you, but it results in an error message: https://imgur.com/EA93ZTc 

I am not quite sure whether I should state the exact row or range in either of these lines:
  try { return range.map(row => do_replace(row[0])) } // for a range

  catch(e) { return do_replace(range) }               // for a single cell

Comment: Put your html lists in the cells A1, A2, A3, etc and put the formula `=to_table(A:A)` in the cell B1. Don't run the code from Script Editor. Custom formula fires by itself whenever you put it into a cell.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yuri! That solved it!